# Flutter - ScrollView is under the appBar

Tags: flutter

I need to have a gradient behind my appBar so my scaffold has the `extendBodyBehindAppBar` set to `true`:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
      drawer: const Drawer(),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
        title: 'Wine Shop',
        appContext: context,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 380,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        colors: [
                          Color(0xFFF9C14C),
                          Color(0xFFF5A328),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: SafeArea(
                      child: _searchInput(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 160,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (c, i) {
                          return _slideCard();
                        },
                        itemCount: 5,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            _buildPopularSection(context),
            _buildRecommendedSection(context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

the problem is that when I scroll the view the content is placed above the appBar:

[image]
[image]

This is my AppBar widget:

```dart
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String title;
  final BuildContext appContext;
  const CustomAppBar({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.appContext,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0.0,
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 26.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        AppBarIcon(
          icon: Icons.shopping_cart,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(56.0);
}
```

If I remove `extendBodyBehindAppBar` the content goes under the appBar, what am I missing?

Comment: u don't need to pass context & set ur Appbar( backgroundColor: ...) . Bcz u set ur AppColor to transparent & extendBodyBehindAppBar to true thats why u r seeing ur extend body through Appbar*( appbar doesn't have any color)

Comment: If I set the backgroundColor I lost my LinearGradient

Comment: then u can do one thing declare ur AppBar inside of ur Column, before ur SizedBox*(height:380)

Comment: no, in that way the appbar is not fixed anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your `SingleScrollView` into `Stack` and adjust your layout a little bit, check code below:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
        title: "Title",
        appContext: context,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 380,
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  colors: [
                    Color(0xFFF9C14C),
                    Color(0xFFF5A328),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              // replace with your search input here
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                child: const Text(
                  "Search",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 220),
            // replace ListView with your SingleScrollView
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: const Text("item 1"),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: const Text("item 2"),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: const Text("item 3"),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: const Text("item 4"),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: const Text("item 5"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Effect:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

give this a try

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 380,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        colors: [
                          Color(0xFFF9C14C),
                          Color(0xFFF5A328),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
        // add Column here & put ur searchInput inside of it
               Column(
                children: [
                 SafeArea(child: _searchInput()), 
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 160,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (c, i) {
                          return _slideCard();
                        },
                        itemCount: 5,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```